# There is no user provider for user App Entity User Shouldn't the supportsClass() method of your user provider return true for this classname?

Tags: symfony-4.4

I created an Email/Password Login form & have a great disappointing problem :(

First of all, This is what I got (I'm using Symfony 4.4.18):
[image]

& these are my codes:

This is the User Entity (supportsClass() method added)App\Entity\User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/", message="Enter Valid Email")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=11)
     */
    private $phone_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="New password can not be blank.")
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$/", message="Minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special character")
     */
    private $password;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $first_name): self
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $last_name): self
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhoneNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone_number;
    }

    public function setPhoneNumber(string $phone_number): self
    {
        $this->phone_number = $phone_number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        return [
            'ROLE_USER'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getUsername() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->first_name,
            $this->last_name,
            $this->email,
            $this->phone_number,
            $this->password,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->first_name,
            $this->last_name,
            $this->email,
            $this->phone_number,
            $this->password,
            ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === User::class;
    }

}
```

The Login Form Authenticator App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator(didn't use bin/console make:auth):

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' =>$request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' =>$request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
        if (!$user) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException("Email Not Found!");
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if (!$targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('dashboard'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

the Login Controller App\Controller\LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationUtils $utils
     * @return Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $utils): Response
    {
        $error = $utils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastEmail = $utils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('login/login.html.twig', [
            'error' => $error,
            'email' => $lastEmail,
        ]);
    }
    
    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {

    }
}
```

login.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}LoginController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <style>
        .error {color: red;}
    </style>
    <h1 class="page-title">Login</h1>
    <div class="page-title">
        {% if error %}
            <span class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</span>
        {% endif %}

        {% if app.user %}
            <div class="mb-3">
                You are logged in as {{ app.user.firstName }}, <a href="{{ path('logout') }}">Logout</a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <form method="post">
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ email }}" placeholder="Email here ...">
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password here ...">

            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

security.yaml config:

```
security:

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        user_provider:
            entity:
                class: APP\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            provider: user_provider

            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

            logout:
                path: logout

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I don't have any idea about supportsClass().
& tried User Repository for custom user provider before but they didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here: `APP\Entity\User -> App\Entity\User`

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to security.yaml then change **APP\ntity\User ---> to App\Entity\User**